# Edx-platform localization doesn't take effect

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, edx, transifex

As per this link: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Internationalization-and-localization

Edx is still showing in english .. to be exact, I did the following items:

1- created a ~/.transifexrc file as root

2- added those items to it:

```
[https://www.transifex.com]
hostname = https://www.transifex.com
username = user
password = pass
token =
```

3- switched to edxapp environment

- `source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env`
- `cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform`

4- changed the language code `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ar'` in `lms/envs/common.py`

5- pulled all the translation files:

- `$ paver i18n_robot_pull`

Now, what shall be done, as the web interface still shows in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I knew that the above change has been working, as I tested things in development mode with a custom `devstack` settings file by directly setting the required lang. code in `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable, then ran those dev. servers to see how things will work:

- `/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/manage.py lms runserver --settings=devstack 0.0.0.0:9999`
- And so did with the Studio app
- `/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/manage.py lms runserver --settings=devstack 0.0.0.0:9999`

Both were working fine ... I'm on the right path !!

After doing the above steps (listed in the question), I did also the following

I changed the `LANGUAGE_CODE` to the desired lang. code in both of the following files inside this directory `/edx/app/edxapp`

- `lms.env.json`
- `cms.env.json`

Then I restarted all the workers in `supervisors` so that the change can take effect:

- `source /edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/bin/activate`
- `supervisorctl restart all`

P.S. It might take a minute or two after supervisord restart so changes take effect

Now everything works beautifully !!